# Pysark out of memory issues with large dataset

Tags: python, apache-spark, join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i got this error:

`An error occurred while calling o154.save. Job aborted due to stage failure: Total size of serialized results of 781 tasks (2.0 GiB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (2.0 GiB)`

and then i set spark.driver.maxResultSize to 0 and then i got

`An error occurred while calling o284.save. Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 345 in stage 4.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 345.4 in stage 4.0 (TID 4997) (172.34.170.137 executor 85): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 85 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.`

it was a simple code i ran:

```
spark_df1=spark.read.csv(path,
        header=False,
        schema=schema,
).repartition("country").alias('b')

dim_table=spark_df1.select([
            "customerid",
            "region",
            "country"]).distinct().alias("d")

joined_dim_table = dim_table.join(date,how='outer').alias('a')

datasink3 =joined_dim_table.repartition("country").write.partitionBy("country").format("csv").option("compression","gzip").save(destination_path)
```

**The size of the file is 130 GB(in zipped csv format) in S3**

Comment: What's your question? Why that huge file does not fit in your RAM?

Comment: A compressed 130 GB CSV can easily be several TB in size while uncompressed. If your spark cluster does not have sufficient memory, then you won't be able to load it in memory for processing. It's probably worth streaming the file and processing in chunks.

Comment: @PApostol yeah technically your methodology works. but i have 50 countries and i have added a filter for spark_df1 for each country. So this process is currently serial. Is there a way to parallelize this and improve speed? For context i have 50 work worker nodes with me.